# Is there a way to hide schemas for openapi in azure function v3?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, swagger-ui, openapi

I have a function app with openapi configuration and I want to Disable Models Section

I have configured openApi in the  project

```
public static async Task Main()
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
                  .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(worker => 
                                            worker.UseNewtonsoftJson())
                  .ConfigureOpenApi()  
    }
```

In the function I have open API attributes defined

```
[OpenApiOperation(operationId: nameof(TestNotificationHttpFunction), tags: new[] { "Test Integration API" }, Summary = "Queue Test Notification", Description = "This API Integrates TestOperations.")]    
[OpenApiRequestBody(contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(TestNotification), Required = true, Description = "TestNotification to process")]
[OpenApiSecurity("function_key", SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Header, Name = "x-functions-key")]
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "text/plain", bodyType: typeof(bool), Description = "testNotification Queued Or Not")]    
[OpenApiResponseWithoutBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Description = "The operation was not completed successfully")]
```

I want to disable Section **Models**, it is possible?.

In the Api I have removed like this

```
 app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
 {
    options.DefaultModelsExpandDepth(-1);
 }
```

I don´t know how to disable in azure functions

Answer (score -1):

If you want to `disable it locally` using Azure Functions:

1. Go to `local.settings.json`
2. Go to `Values` sections.
3. Add `"OpenApi__HideSwaggerUI": "true"`

You should have something like this:

[image]

Now if you go to swagger page you will have `HTTP ERROR 404`

If you want to `disable it in production` you can:

1. Go to the azure function that you want to disable swagger.
2. Go to Settings > Configuration panel.
3. Click in New Application settings.
4. Enter `"OpenApi__HideSwaggerUI": "true"`
5. Click Ok and save your new Azure Function Configuration.

[image]

Now after the server restarts you can go to swagger page and you will have `HTTP ERROR 404`

Here is full documentation:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/blob/main/docs/openapi.md